# Jasny reveal menu - canvas not being full height splits the page

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, canvas

I am using Jasny Reveal menu which uses a z-index style in order to make the menu appear static behind a moving canvas / main body. The issue is that if the canvas is not full height then it splits the page - best illustrated by this image which is when the menu is in mid-movement.

[menu issue http://elementdevelopment.co.uk/menu-issue.jpg](http://elementdevelopment.co.uk/menu-issue.jpg)

Behaviour can be seen here [also](http://www.elementdevelopment.co.uk/kam2.0/). If I apply the button to the body rather than the .canvas then it creates all sorts of issues.

Many thanks

Comment: This is probably because of the fact the wrapper class doesn't have a 100% height.

Comment: That does not make any difference I am afraid.

Comment: The real question is why `min-height: 100%` on `.wrapper` isn't working, even when adding `height: 100%` to `html` and `min-height: 100%` to `body`. This isn't directly caused by the use of the `.navmenu`.